# set vim to autoindent using the same characters as the previous line

Tags: vim, indentation, spaces

I use tabs for indentation in all my files. However, some bigger projects still use spaces, so I also need to follow those guidelines when I contribute.

This issue could easily be solved if the editor would detect the indent character used in the edited file, and use that one when e.g. autoindenting.

Sadly, `vim` forces spaces for indent, even when I am editing a file which otherwise only uses tabs.

How can I tell vim to always just use what the file is using (and use tabs if the file isn't using anything)?

I tried adding the following line (as I understand it, this should be forcing tabs - not exactly what I want, but better than inserting spaces everywhere) to `~/.vimrc` and reopening the file I was editing, but this failed to take effect.

I am running `vim-8.0.0386`.

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth Does a fairly good job of setting the indentation setting based off of the current / surrounding files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [tpope/sleuth](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth%20tpope/vim-sleuth) plugin is exactly what you want.

Otherwise, [DetectIndent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1171) works too.
Clone the DetectIndent repo in your *.vim/bundle/* directory (I use pathogen to install plugins), then open any file and type: `:DetectIndent`

Now shiftwidth, expandtab and tabstop should be adjusted to your file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another plugin recommendation: My [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690). It does not only detect the used indent setting, but also warns you if inconsistent settings are used within the same file.